# update dict using nested for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have the double for loop below.  In the first for loop I'm iterating through the elements in tstLst1 and for each element I'm then iterating through the elements in tstLst2, testing each element to see if it's greater then 5, then appending the elements from tstLst2 in a new 
list tstEmpt1.  I then update dict with the list of values from tstLst2 for each element of tstLst1 as keys.  I'm getting the "Nonetype" error below, I'm not sure why.  Can someone please point out the issue and suggest a solution?

Code:

```
tstLst1=[1,2,3]
tstLst2=[2,5,6]

tstDict1={}



for j in tstLst1:

    tstEmpt1=[]

    for i in tstLst2:

        if i >5:

            tstEmpt1=tstEmpt1.append(i)

    tstDict1=tstDict1.update({j:tstEmpt1})
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-89e025227797> in <module>
     16             tstEmpt1=tstEmpt1.append(i)
     17 
---> 18     tstDict1=tstDict1.update({j:tstEmpt1})
     19 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `list.append()` returns `None` so when you do `tstEmpt1=tstEmpt1.append(i)` you're appending the element and assigning `None` to the list. Next iteration throws because `None` has no attribute 'update' as the error states.

Same case with the `dictionary.update()`.

Removing the assignments should do the trick for you:

```
for j in tstLst1:
  tstEmpt1=[]
  for i in tstLst2:
    if i >5:
      tstEmpt1.append(i)
  tstDict1.update({j:tstEmpt1})
```